# Computer not turning off, but display stops

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

So I have a W10 machine, however then I click to "Shutdown" the system, the screens stop receiving input but the system remains running. I can both see the lights indicating it's working and hear all the fans still running. I've left it over night hoping it was just waiting to finish a task, however it didn't turn off.

Specs:

- OS: W10
- MB: Asus Crosshair Formula-z
- CPU: AMD 8350fx black edition
- GPU: AMD 280x
- RAM: 16GB DDR3 (can't remember exact specs will update
     once home)

Completely up to date on all updates.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to -1 please can you at least state why so I can edit the question and learn what to not do?

Comment: For the sake of improvement, maybe it was down voted because you don't ask an actual question. We can assume you want to know how to resolve the issue, but we would be guessing that is what you want. Or maybe because your post shows a lack of research effort. There are details missing, like; Is this a new machine? Laptop or desktop? Is this a new problem, has it always done this? Have you run hardware diagnostics? Adding any of these will improve your question.